# Vite assets bundler not bundling all files during Docker build for Laravel application with Inertia.js and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, docker, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I have a Laravel application with frontend built using Inertia.js and Vue.js, and I am using Vite as the assets bundler. When I run `vite build` locally, the application gets bundled correctly, including all assets. However, when I try to build the Docker image for the application, Vite bundles `app.js` and `app.css` only, leaving out the rest of the assets.

Here the resources folder tree:

```
resources
├── css
│   └── app.css
├── images
│   └── logo.png
└── js
    ├── app.js
    └── pages
        └── Quote
            ├── Create.vue
            └── Show.vue
```

Here the expected output:

```
vite v4.4.7 building for production...
✓ 100 modules transformed.
public/build/manifest.json                                     1.24 kB │ gzip:  0.33 kB
public/build/assets/logo-fae5368c.png                      2,792.47 kB
public/build/assets/Show-4ec4a01e.css                          0.03 kB │ gzip:  0.05 kB
public/build/assets/app-c7d1a54e.css                           7.29 kB │ gzip:  2.23 kB
public/build/assets/Create-742e3950.js                         3.06 kB │ gzip:  1.20 kB
public/build/assets/Show-9b783249.js                           3.90 kB │ gzip:  1.71 kB
public/build/assets/app-4b5ce87a.js                          166.41 kB │ gzip: 59.79 kB
✓ built in 5.57s
```

Here the current result building with Docker:

```
vite v4.4.7 building for production...
✓ 95 modules transformed.
rendering chunks...
computing gzip size...
public/build/manifest.json              0.26 kB │ gzip:  0.13 kB
public/build/assets/app-179954eb.css    0.06 kB │ gzip:  0.06 kB
public/build/assets/app-1e574fbf.js   161.97 kB │ gzip: 57.94 kB
✓ built in 2.52s
```

Here the `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Here the `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG composer_version=latest
ARG node_version=latest
ARG php_version=fpm

FROM php:$php_version as base

RUN \
    apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
      exif \
      pdo_mysql \
      zip

RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

WORKDIR /var/www/html

FROM composer:$composer_version as composer

FROM base as vendor

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

ARG nova_email
ARG nova_password

RUN \
    composer config --global http-basic.nova.laravel.com ${nova_email} ${nova_password} \
    && composer install \
        --no-autoloader \
        --no-dev \
        --no-interaction \
        --no-plugins \
        --no-scripts \
        --prefer-dist

COPY . .

RUN composer dumpautoload

FROM node:$node_version as build

WORKDIR /root

COPY \
    package.json \
    yarn.lock \
    vite.config.js \
    ./
COPY resources/js resources/js/
COPY resources/css resources/css/
COPY resources/images resources/images/

RUN \
  yarn --production \
  && yarn build

FROM base

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source=https://github.com/...

COPY --from=vendor /var/www/html .

COPY --from=build /root/public/build public/build/

RUN php artisan nova:publish

RUN \
    chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www \
    && chmod ug+w -R /var/www/html/storage/
```

Here's what I have tried:

- Tried to run the command locally in a folder containing only the necessary files (as Docker).
- Tried rebuilding the Docker image from scratch, but the issue persists.
- Tried to list files during Docker build just before `vite build` command and the files are present as well.

I expected Vite to bundle all the assets correctly during the Docker build, just like it does in the local environment. But it seems to be missing some files during the build process.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with Vite during Docker builds? Is there something I am missing in my Dockerfile or Vite configuration? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.